# SVN to GIT repositories migration, Error : could not lock the config / metadata file

Tags: git

Basically i am migrating all my SVN repositories one by one to GIT remote, but in between I'm getting the following error when i try to fetch the metadata for SVN repository

**Error:**

```
error: could not lock config file .git/svn/.metadata: File exists
config svn-remote.REPOSITORYNAME https://svn01.comapnyname.com/svn/repos/REPOSITORYNAME: command returned error: 255
```

any help? how to solve this?

Comment: after doing the research and understood that i need to remove the .metadata.lock file under .git/svn/. I have deleted the file and its working.

Comment: Since you've found the solution, could you please post an answer and accept it?

Answer (score 3):

after doing the research and understood that i need to remove the .metadata.lock file under .git/svn/ I have deleted the file and its working good.

And also sometime the single branch under repository will take more time (more than 24 hrs), but at finally the migration will success.